# Form validation is not fired in the before send call back function using jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am very new to jQuery.I have done a simple task that validation form data using jQuery validation plugin.

I have created a simple form

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script src="js/form-validate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
   <fieldset>
     <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>
     <p>
       <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
       <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" class =" requiredFieldCheck ">
     </p>
     <p>
       <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
       <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required>
     </p>
     <p>
       <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
       <input id="curl" type="url" name="url">
     </p>
     <p>
       <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
       <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
     </p>
     <p>
       <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
     </p>
   </fieldset>
 </form>
<script>
//$("#commentForm").validate();
$(function(){

        $('#commentForm').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend:function(){
            alert('before send');
            $('#commentForm').validate();
        },
        success:function(){
            
            alert("when success");
            
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('when unsuccess');
        }
    });

    $('#commentForm').ajaxSubmit();

    // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
    return false;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
$.validator.addMethod("requiredFieldCheck", function (value, element) {
    alert("working method requiredFieldCheck "+value);
    var result;
     if(value.length > 3){
  result = true ;
 }
 else{
  result = false ;
 }
 return result;
}, '****This content must be greater than 3 characters****');
```

And also in the browser console it is caught by an error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
Can anyone give me some suggestions to do form validation before sending data and essesntially using jquery validation plugin? 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: `Undefined is not a function` - Where you are getting this error? On which line?

Comment: $('#commentForm').ajaxForm(    in this line I am getting an error

Comment: There might be several problems. First thing are you loading `jquery.form.js`. If yes, please post the order how you are loading your `js` files because there might be possibilities of loading `js` files twice which might cause problem~~

Comment: I have added jquery.form.js inside my js folder and added in the script tag.Now I do not get the console error.But the moment I have clicked the submit button it shows the error not when I first click submit button.why is that?

Comment: Now where it is showing??

Comment: I have put an alert ..And through the alert am checking whether the custom validations are working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75376/discussion-between-raji-satkunam-and-guruprasad-rao).

Comment: Is it working?? If no what is happening??

Comment: ya it's working when the submit button clicked second time.Not when the first time it was clicked.I need to know Why is it happening?

Comment: Put a break point in console once and see whether function is hitting first time when you click...

Answer (score 0):

you need to register adapter, for example:

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("requiredFieldCheck", "other");
```

Comment: I could not get you clearly where do I want to add this adapter ?

Comment: do you load JQueryForm plugin? it looks like it missing.
if you do load it, and in the correct order, then you should register the adapter just before the add method line.

Comment: I have added jquery.form.js inside my js folder and added in the script tag.Now I do not get the console error.But the moment I have clicked the submit button twice it shows the error but not when I first click submit button.why is that?